# Kendo window scrollbar with fixed height

Tags: kendo-ui

I am trying to add scrollbar to kendo witndow with fixed height but it is not worked.

Please help me , below are my code

```
var Employee= $('#EmpData');
    Employee.kendoWindow(
                    {
                        title: "Employee Data",
                        width: "779px",
                        height: "700px",
                        animation: false,
                        resizable: false,
                        modal: true,
                        actions: [
                            "Minimize",
                             "Maximize",
                                    "Close"
                        ],
                        visible: true,

                       // scrollable: true
                    }).data('kendoWindow');
    $('#EmpData').data('kendoWindow').center().open();
```

As if data is more than popup size then it cuts ,i need to show scrollbar to kendo window if data exceeds.

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Here is a [demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/OJuqiz/2) which shows that kendo does it automatically. Check css if you are not changing something by mistake.

Comment: @Ademar : ok .. thanks